# SVN - Merge branch to trunk, overwrites some trunk changes / new features

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, trunk

So... I have a problem where I created a branch (0.1) and fixed a few things there, but meanwhile I was working on new things in trunk.

Now I want to merge branch (0.1) to trunk and before commit I did diff and I saw that some changes should be used from trunk not branch (new URLs and new function names for example) but there was no conflict reported.

How do I deal with that? Should I do the reverse merge? -> trunk to the copy of new branch (for example: 0.1-TEST) and then merge new branch (0.1-TEST) back to trunk?

Comment: so, when you merge you realized few changes that you wanted to be from trunk are overwritten by merge... you just wanted selective merging, right?

Comment: Can you give the exact command you have used to merge the changes?

Comment: You should be able to merge from the branch as described.  I would check when and where the unwanted changes were made, if you made branch specific changes after branching then you will have to manually exclude those from the merge before committing. You will only get a conflict if changes were made in a similar location on both the branch and the trunk after the branch was made.  If a change only took place on the trunk and no similar change was on the branch it should remain intact if the correct command was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be taking changes from the trunk and merging them into your branch.  That way your branch is always as up to date as possible.  Having said that if you didn't get conflicts with the first merge, odds are doing it again you are not going to get any conflicts.  I know it sucks but you're probably going to have to manually look and remove the changes from the branch that you didn't want in the trunk.

Comment: I disagree with the claim you should always be moving changes from the trunk to a branch.  This really depends on the purpose of the branch e.g. a stable branch (maybe used for a release) would only expect very limited porting of changes to it from other locations.

Comment: So what's the rule of thumb for merging branch->trunk or trunk->branch? In which cases should I prefer which?

Comment: @MatjazMuhic My work cycle normally is as follows:  I have something to big to be done in the trunk so I make a branch.  Then I work in both the branch and the trunk and when I have a bunch of changes in the trunk I merge them into the branch.  Then when I'm finished with the work in the branch I merge the branch back into the trunk.  The key is never getting to out of sync.

Comment: @morechilli I guess I used the word always incorrectly; yes for release branches it doesn't make sense to merge the trunk into the branch, as that would defeat the purpose of the branch.  But for branches that you're doing side work on, like in Matjazs case, its always good to keep the branch in sync with the trunk.